# parentNode is null – traversing DOM to construct XPath

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, xpath, puppeteer

This function returns the XPath of element `e`, given a `puppeteer` handle `e` and its page `page`:

```js
async function getXpathOfElement(page, e) {
  return await page.evaluate(e => {
    var xpath = "";
    var pos, tmpitem2;

    while (e !== document.documentElement) {
      pos = 0;
      tmpitem2 = e;

      while (tmpitem2) {
        // if is ELEMENT_NODE of the same name
        if (tmpitem2.nodeType === 1 && tmpitem2.nodeName === e.nodeName) {
          ++pos;
        }
        tmpitem2 = tmpitem2.previousSibling;
      }

      xpath = e.nodeName + "[" + pos + ']' + '/' + xpath;
      e = e.parentNode;
    }

    xpath = '/' + document.documentElement.nodeName + '/' + xpath;
    xpath = xpath.replace(/\/$/, '');

    return xpath;
  }, e);
}
```

It works as intended, but not always: with a specific pair of `page` and `e`, after `while` completes a few loops, `e.parentNode` becomes `null`, with `e` being a valid `<div>` DOM node whose parent is a `<li>`, as I observed from html.

It's interesting that `while` completes a few loops before the issue, so the DOM structure is partially traversed.

Comment: It's possible that you're passing an `e` that belongs to a different document or to a detached subtree. You should step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: After the line where `getXpathOfElement` is called, the same handle `e` is successfully used as in `e.click()` on the same `page`, with the function `getXpathOfElement` commented out for test. I believe this contradicts your propositions.